# Screen going black and OS not booting

Tags: linux, boot, drivers, grub, kernel

Using Manjaro KDE.

In an attempt to install nvidia drivers, i blacklisted the nouveau drivers typing "blacklist nouveau" in /etc/modprobe.d/nouveau_blacklist.conf and then rebooted. *Didn't reboot
Now i only boot to the grub bootloader and when i choose Manjaro the screen goes black (but is turned on) and nothing happens. When i power-kick it, i see a white text a milisecond before the screen turns off if that helps.
I am writing this from Windows on the same machine - dual boot. I think what might be happening is -
everything functions but nothing is displayed since the drivers are blacklisted. Now can I edit the file from Windows (i'm not even sure i can access the other disk from here) or from the grub terminal?
I can do anything from Windows if needed. I appreciate any help.

Comment: Do you have the openssh-server running? Then log in remote. If not, you know why you need to install that by default. Another option is to boot from a USB live stick like Ubuntu, edit that config file back to its original.

Comment: I don't understand. I don't have openssh-server installed. Why would i need it?

Comment: OpenSSH lets you login from another computer (or even your phone if you use an SSH app), even if no display is working or connected, so you can run terminal commands.  At the very least you could have reverted your change that broke your system.

Comment: Ok i am going to try that. Thank you

Comment: I will suggest to create a live USB of Linux distro and chroot into Manjaro from live USB and make necessary changes .